# Run processes on ios when phone is locked

Tags: ios

Can you still run processes in your app while phone is locked such as the gyroscope? I know there are apps like Waze a gps app and it can still fetch your location if your phone is locked or if you're not on the app. So can you use the gyroscope as well while the app is locked. Are there any special techniques to doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS, there are two different options for running background tasks:

1. Use `[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]` ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a)) - this allows you to run a background task while your app is not active. This task is limited to 10-15 minutes and is usually used to complete downloading a file, finish a long ongoing task etc.
2. Long-running tasks, such as location query or audio playback are also available, but your app needs to ask a special permission for it (defined in your project's `Info.plist` file). You can find the complete list [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20). Sadly, it doesn't seem that Gyroscope events (defined in Core Motion) can be used in that manner.